# Want to select a random item from a list and reuse the item in a different function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, python-requests

my code is pretty messy as I am new but I cant figure this out!

I have only included the relevant pieces of my code btw.

Pretty much What i want it to do is say the same location twice for random_place1 and then a new location for random_place2. Currently it just gives me three separate locations, because i am just calling for random_place1 to rerandomize.

```
def random_place1():

    import random

    locations = ["Paris" , "New York", "San Francisco" , "Tokyo", "Istanbul", "São Paulo", "Xi'an", "Bogotá", "Casablanca", "Rabat"]


    first_place = random.choice(locations)

    return (first_place)

def random_place2():

    import random

    locations = ["London" , "Miami" , "Chicago", "Cairo", "Vienna" , "Manila", "Munich", "Delhi"]


    second_place = random.choice(locations)
    return(second_place)

def main():

    answer = input("Type Yes to continue or No to exit: ")
    if answer == "yes":
        print("\nLast summer, we went for a vacation with " + random_name(), "on a trip to " + random_place1(), ". The weather there is very " + random_adj(), "! Northern " + random_place1(), " has many " + random_plural_noun(), ", and they make " + random_plural_noun(), " there. Many people there also go to the " + random_place2()," to " + random_action_verb(), ". The people who live there like to eat " + random_food(), ". They also like to " + random_action_verb(), " in the sun and swim in the " + random_noun(), ". It was a really " + random_adj(), " trip!")
        restart2()
    elif answer == "y" :
        print("\nLast summer, we went for a vacation with " + random_name(), "on a trip to " + random_place1(), ". The weather there is very " + random_adj(), "! Northern " + random_place1(), " has many " + random_plural_noun(), ", and they make " + random_plural_noun(), " there. Many people there also go to the " + random_place2()," to " + random_action_verb(), ". The people who live there like to eat " + random_food(), ". They also like to " + random_action_verb(), " in the sun and swim in the " + random_noun(), ". It was a really " + random_adj(), " trip!")
        restart2()
    elif answer == "Yes":
        print("\nLast summer, we went for a vacation with " + random_name(), "on a trip to " + random_place1(), ". The weather there is very " + random_adj(), "! Northern " + random_place1(), " has many " + random_plural_noun(), ", and they make " + random_plural_noun(), " there. Many people there also go to the " + random_place2()," to " + random_action_verb(), ". The people who live there like to eat " + random_food(), ". They also like to " + random_action_verb(), " in the sun and swim in the " + random_noun(), ". It was a really " + random_adj(), " trip!")
        restart2()
    elif answer == "YES":
        print("\nLast summer, we went for a vacation with " + random_name(), "on a trip to " + random_place1(), ". The weather there is very " + random_adj(), "! Northern " + random_place1(), " has many " + random_plural_noun(), ", and they make " + random_plural_noun(), " there. Many people there also go to the " + random_place2()," to " + random_action_verb(), ". The people who live there like to eat " + random_food(), ". They also like to " + random_action_verb(), " in the sun and swim in the " + random_noun(), ". It was a really " + random_adj(), " trip!")
        restart2()
    elif answer == "Y":
        print("\nLast summer, we went for a vacation with " + random_name(), "on a trip to " + random_place1(), ". The weather there is very " + random_adj(), "! Northern " + random_place1(), " has many " + random_plural_noun(), ", and they make " + random_plural_noun(), " there. Many people there also go to the " + random_place2()," to " + random_action_verb(), ". The people who live there like to eat " + random_food(), ". They also like to " + random_action_verb(), " in the sun and swim in the " + random_noun(), ". It was a really " + random_adj(), " trip!")
        restart2()

    elif answer == "no":
        print("\nThanks for trying out the Madlibs Generator!")
    elif answer == "n":
        print("\nThanks for trying out the Madlibs Generator!")
    elif answer == "No":
        print("\nThanks for trying out the Madlibs Generator!")
    elif answer == "NO":
        print("\nThanks for trying out the Madlibs Generator!")
    elif answer == "N":
        print("\nThanks for trying out the Madlibs Generator!")
    else:
        print("\nInvalid response please try again!")
        restart()
```

Comment: leaving a side any other issues in your code, after you capture the answer, just generate and store the random places before you print them like `loc1 = random_place1()` then in your text just use `loc1` instead of `random_place1()`

Comment: When I try this it still gives me two different locations rather than one.

Comment: that cannot be possible. So if you do `loc1 = random_place1(); print(f"{loc1} {loc1}")` you are saying you get two different locations?

Comment: Yes. The issue i think arrises is it is just calling random_places() again bringing in a new city. Maybe doing something with random.seed()? I just dont know how to clear and reset the seed after the first go through.

Comment: NNo you are doing something wrong here. Look at the answer i posted earlier, its a fully working example and shows location1 doesnt change

Comment: I tried copying and pasting that into a file and trying just what you wrote and that didnt produce anything at all. It says 


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "help.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "help.py", line 13, in main
    location1 = random_place(locations1)
  File "help.py", line 7, in random_place
    return random.choice(locations)
NameError: name 'random' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You can call the random place methods and store the value it returns in a variable to use that value later. One coding principle you might want to look at is called "DRY" (Dont repeat yourself). If you see your self writing a lot of the same code then chances are you can take a better approach.

So below is just a quick update of your code to make it cleaner. You could really not bother with the func random_place as instead of calling it from main we could just call random.choice. However i have included it to show you that you dont need to write random_place twice. you could write it once and give it a locations to chose from.

Also you can take the input and make it lower case. then you only need to test for things like "yes" or "y" you dont need to test for all the case sensitive version. Thus you only write the print line once.

```py
import random

locations1 = ["Paris", "New York", "San Francisco", "Tokyo", "Istanbul", "São Paulo", "Xi'an", "Bogotá", "Casablanca",
              "Rabat"]
locations2 = ["London", "Miami", "Chicago", "Cairo", "Vienna", "Manila", "Munich", "Delhi"]

def random_place(locations):
    return random.choice(locations)

def main():
    while True:
        answer = input("Type Yes to continue or No to exit: ").lower()
        if answer == "yes" or answer == "y":
            location1 = random_place(locations1)
            location2 = random_place(locations2)
            print(f"Last year i went to {location1}. This year i was going to go again to {location1}.",
                  f"However my friends suggested to go to {location2} as the people in {location2} are nicer")

        elif answer == "no" or answer == "n":
            print("\nThanks for trying out the Madlibs Generator!")
            break

        else:
            print("\nThats not a valid input")


main()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Type Yes to continue or No to exit: yes
Last year i went to São Paulo. This year i was going to go again to São Paulo. However my friends suggested to go to Manila as the people in Manila are nicer
Type Yes to continue or No to exit: nodf

Thats not a valid input
Type Yes to continue or No to exit: no

Thanks for trying out the Madlibs Generator!
```